# Python long list separated

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
x =['Adam', 'G', '24', '1983', 'Aug', 'August Birthday', 'Steve', 'F', '31', '1970', 'Sep', 'sept bday']
```

I would like to get the above list into another list but in a way I can work with it like this

```
x = [('Adam', 'G', '24', '1983', 'Aug', 'August Birthday'),('Steve', 'F', '31', '1970', 'Sep', 'sept bday')]

The Pattern is x = [(0,1,2,3,4,5),(0,1,2,3,4,5)] etc....
```

What is a good way to do this?

I have tried to iterate over the list using a count and after each line adding 1 to the count so I can get to 6 then start count over again, but I am not sure how to get it into the desired list.

Comment: It may also be worth looking at how that first list is generated in the first place and changing that unless you also need it in the long format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
size_of_new = 5
print zip(*[iter(x)]*size_of_new)
```

is my favorite way of doing this ... however

```
[x[i:i+size_of_new] for i in range(0,len(x),size_of_new)]
```

is maybe more readable

Comment: I know what the asterisk means in the first example, but I am surprised by the fact that you don't put a comma between *[iter(x)] and *size_of_new. Why is this?

Comment: because its really more like `zip(*[1]*3)` => `zip(*[1,1,1])` ,whereas  `zip(*[1],*3)` would result in an error

Comment: Your first example truncates `len(x) % size_of_new` elements at the end of list `x`.

Comment: Yeah... But that shouldn't matter given the problem statement